# Google Maps - create marker and make it fade away

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to create a marker and then have it fade away over the course of about 5 seconds.  Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct why to do this with the API, though there a probably a few ways you do something like it. One, you could make a bunch of images with varying opacity and set the icon for the marker a bunch of times within the 5 seconds. Two, you could use the vector overlays (e.g. polygon), which have the opacity options, instead of markers.